# Client side validation with judge not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use client side validation with Judge gem but validation not working.

In my gem file I used

```
# Forms
gem 'simple_form', '3.0.2'

#Client side validations
gem 'judge'
```

I have simlpe_form gem and I know i need to use plugin for simple form with judge but i am trying to use in normal form_for but its not working with that either.

My model looks like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 10

  validates :name , presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
```

In my view

```
- title 'User Registration'

.vcentered
 .signup-box
  - if @user.authorizations.any?
   %h1 We just need a little more information...
  - else
   %h1 We just need a little bit of information...

  = form_for @user,:builder => Judge::FormBuilder, url: user_registration_path, html: { class: 'new-user form-default' } do |f|
   - if @user.name.blank?
    = f.text_field :name, class: class_with_errors(@user, :name),
                          title: title_with_errors(@user, :name),
                          placeholder: 'Full Name',
                          :validate => true
```

I have followed all configuration stps as given on github page of gem.
Please suggest solution of the problem or how I can find the cause of problem. 
in client side validation when i load the page browser is saying (at top middle, I forget what it is called)

The page at localhost: 3000 says: PAge can't be blank. Any idea why it is working like this ?

Comment: in client side validation

when i load the page browser is saying (at top middle, I forget what it is called)

The page at localhost: 3000 says: Page can't be blank


any idea why it is working like this?

Comment: above problem solved but new problem arrived

Answer (score 0):

rails generate judge:install path/to/your/js/dir

and then in your route.rb

mount Judge::Engine => '/judge'

Comment: path/to/your/js/dir means app/assets/javascripts right ?